# Ajax.Begin form not rendering correct action .NET mvc4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

I'm running into a bizarre issue with my Ajax form. I am trying to post to my cart controller when a user clicks an add to cart button. I simply want to post the product ID from a hidden field, and return a string and update a div with either a success of fail message. The following Razor markup is in my view...

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Carts", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess="OnSuccess", HttpMethod="Post", Url="/Carts/AddToCart/"  }, new { @style = "display:inline-block"}))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Product_ID)
            <input type="submit" class="button round large primary" value="Add To Cart" />
        }
```

And in my cart controller, I have the following code to add to cart, and return a string that I can either use javascript to update the div that I want to display the message or have the framework handle for me.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult AddToCart(int product_ID)
        {
            if (db.Products.Any(product => product.Product_ID == product_ID))
            {
                //var successfulAddToCart = false;
                var cartItem = new Cart();

               // cartItem.CartID = Guid.NewGuid();

                if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    cartItem.Customer = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(customer => customer.Email == User.Identity.Name);
                }                    
                else//not logged in, need to remember them somehow
                {

                    var CartCookie = new HttpCookie("CartID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                    CartCookie.Expires.AddDays(2);
                    Request.Cookies.Add(CartCookie);
                    cartItem.Customer = new Customer();
                }


                cartItem.IsCheckedOut = false;
                cartItem.Quantity = 1;
                cartItem.Sku = db.SKU_Table.FirstOrDefault(sku => sku.Product_ID == product_ID);

                db.Cart.Add(cartItem);
                db.SaveChanges();


                return Content("Add to cart was successful");
            }
            else
                return Content("Add to cart was not successful");


        }
```

Now the main problem that I'm running into is the form is being rendered with the wrong action. Here is what is rendered in html.

[image: Rendered html of the markup]

Now I don't know what the right way to do this in MVC is, as I'm a bit new to the framework, but I would like to avoid making an AJAX call in javascript if there is a better way. I'm not sure what the cause of the mishap with the action being incorrect on the dom. I suspect that it has to do with my route.config file as if I change the order or routes in the file, they have an impact on the result of the action. I can post this in an update if it's relevant but I figure I'd throw this out to the Stack Overflow expertise. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You using the wrong overload, where the 2nd parameter is the route values which is why you get `....?Length=5` (`string` has one property named `Length` and there a 5 characters in 'Carts') . Use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions,System.Object%29) (and remove the unnecessary `Url` option)

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Carts", new { product_ID = Model.Product_ID }, 
    new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess="OnSuccess", HttpMethod="Post" }, 
    new { @style = "display:inline-block"}))
{
    <input type="submit" class="button round large primary" value="Add To Cart" />
}
```

Note also that you do not need the hidden input for the `Product_ID` since its already been added as a route/query string value.

Note also the default `HttpMethod` is `"Post"` so its not necessary to add that option.

Comment: Also, you might want to specify the `UpdateTargetId` property (inside AjaxOptions) if you want to show the result from this ajax form submit.

Comment: It currently renders out the product ID in the html. Does this pose a security issue? /Carts/AddToCart?product_ID=1 is what is rendered out and I feel like it's bad security wise to put out an ID of a database entity in html. Any thoughts on the subject?

Comment: Should not be (you normally add the ID as a route value when making a GET call - e.g. `/Products/Edit/1`, but if its a concern for you, then replace `new { product_ID = Model.Product_ID }` with `null` and add the hidden input back in.

Comment: Note also Shyju's comment - your can add the (say) `UpdateTargetId="message"` option and in the view `<div id="message"></div>` to display the content your returning (although perhaps that's what your `OnSuccess` function is already doing?)

Comment: The AJAX `UpdateTargetId` option doesn't seem to be working. Nor does making my onSuccess function ever get hit. Am I returning the wrong return value from the controller? I'm passing the Content("string in here") return value and it simply brings me to another page. What do I need to do to get that to work?

Comment: If you being redirected, it meas you do not have `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` loaded in th eview or layout (without that file, `Ajax.BeginForm()` makes a normal submit)